# Confusion understanding transient behaviour?

Tags: control, control-system, pid-controller

[image]

I am trying to simulate PID controllers in MATLAB Simulink, but I am bit confused by the term "transient behaviour" in how its extreme highlighted forms (aggressive and robust) will affect the system response?

Here in this context, what will be the meaning of aggressive and robust?

Answer (score 3):

Robust means that your controller will be less affected by plant variations. For example, if your plant transfer function is a crude approximation, you should aim for a more robust controller. It is loosely related to the concept of robustness https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_control

Aggressive means fast rise time. If your model is really accurate, your actuators strong an fast, you can aim for a fast rise time.

Answer (score 2):

These terms are not engineering specs, and not particularly standard. "Aggressive" would suggest fast rise time, possibly with overshoot.  "Robust" suggests that the system "works" across a large set of different inputs.